# Action Script 3 Counter/Button Color Change

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am new to Action Script and need assistance.

Essentially, I have 50 buttons, each button is in the shape of its corresponding state of the United States. My intentions are this, I will have a question display with only one correct answer (for example, which state is the sunshine state?) The objective then is to click on the correct state.

My issue is keeping the score, I figured I could go about this two ways, but I am struggling with both. 
First way would be a counter, if you click on the correct state add a point to the counter, if you click on the incorrect state don't add a point, but wrong or correct, both clicks will take you to the next question. The problem with this is creating a counter, I've tried numerous things and cant seem to get it to work.

The other is option was clicking on the correct state would change the color of that state green, and clicking the wrong state would change the color of the correct state to red with both clicks still taking you to the next question. I've also tried this method and can't seem to figure out how to change the color of the buttons. There isn't much code to show other than the 50 states buttons which I declared (i.e. virginiabutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, virginiabuttonclick);

**EDIT**

So I took out the counter, I don't really need it anymore since the colors are almost working. So the problem I am having is on any question, IF you click on the correct state, turn that correct state green AND go to the next question. IF you click on the wrong state, turn the correct state red AND go to the next question. This code does exactly that except for the the "wrong click" function. When I click on the incorrect state, it just turns the incorrect state(in this case CA) red instead of VA turning red. I think the problem in the code is in the else function where it says "e.currentTarget". I want it to instead change the current correct state to red and not the currrentTarget.

```
var currentCorrectState:DisplayObject; 

var correctColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
correctColor.color = 0x009900; //green

var wrongColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
wrongColor.color = 0x990000; //red

virginiabutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);
californiabutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);
// have just these two in for now just so i have a correct state(va) and incorrect state(ca)

currentCorrectState = virginiabutton
//va is correct state for this question

function buttonClick(e:Event):void {

    if(e.currentTarget == currentCorrectState){
       DisplayObject(e.currentTarget).transform.colorTransform = correctColor;
       gotoAndStop(3);
        //this code works, it transforms VA to green which is what I want. It also goes to the next question.

    }else{
       DisplayObject(e.currentTarget).transform.colorTransform = wrongColor;
        gotoAndStop(3);
        //this code doesn't work, it only transforms the currenTarget state(in this case CA) to red. it also goes to the next question which works. 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of something you could try:

```
var ctr:int = 0; //counter to hold the amount of correct gueses

var currentCorrectState:DisplayObject; //var for holding the current state that is correct.

var correctColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
correctColor.color = 0x009900; //green

var wrongColor:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
wrongColor.color = 0x990000; //red

virginiabutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClick);
//add the rest of click listeners, best to do it in a loop so it's not so tedious

//generic click handler for all buttons
function buttonClick(e:Event):void {
    //turn the correct state the correct color:
    currentCorrectState.transform.colorTransform = correctColor;

    //e.currentTarget is the button that was clicked
    if(e.currentTarget == currentCorrectState){
       ctr++; //increment the correct counter

       //answer was correct, so make the correct state green
       currentCorrectState.transform.colorTransform = correctColor;

       //do anything else you want to do if they answered correct
    }else{
       //answer was incorrect, make the correct state red
       currentCorrectState.transform.colorTransform = wrongColor;
       //do anything else you want to do when they answer incorrect
    }

    //if you have a score text field update it
    score.text = "Your Score: " + ctr;

    //go to the next question (however you do that)
    nextQuestion();

}

function nextQuestion():void {
    //ask your question, however you do that

    //if there was a previous question, reset the last states color
    if(currentCorrectState) currentCorrectState.transform.colorTransform = new ColorTransform();

    //set the correct answer for this new question
    currentCorrectState = virginiabutton; 
}
```

Comment: So I used your code and modified it a little, but I'm still stuck on one problem. Everything is functioning correctly except for the "else" section which is basically when the user selects the wrong state. When I select a wrong state, I want the CORRECT state to turn red and I also want to immediately move to the next question. I was able to get it to move to the next question, however I can only get the "currentTarget" to turn red. Any suggestions on how to initialize it to make it so that the correct state turns red?

Comment: I tweak the code in the answer slightly to address what you'd like to happen